# using if in query sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have a sample data like this :

```
==============================
name    |  class  | action
==============================
abdul       A         1
bedul       B        null
charli      B        null
```

if action = null
i want to display :

```
==============================
name    |  class  | action
==============================
abdul       A         1
bedul               
charli
```

so, how to query to get the results I want.
using sqlserver

thanks...

Comment: consider having a table containing both Action NULL and ACTION NOT NULL, what would you expect as output?

Comment: You can use `CASE WHEN` in your `SELECT` to change `NULL` to blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Select 
    name,
    Case When action is null then '' else class end as class,
    Case When action is null then '' else action end as action
from MyTable
```